# rails form to send to my email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email

On submission of the contact form in my app I am looking to have the form data be sent to my email.

I looked into using action mailer, but on the rails guides it shows configurations for an automated email from you to a new user on signup.

Is there a potential solution out there using simple form?

I can create the form, just need a little help with configuration so it sends to my email.

I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like a normal form, submit request to your rails server. Then your server collect the data and send email to you using [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

If you don't want to do like that, maybe this GEM can help you:

https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form